# Mysql, Retrieve records that have more than X days old

Tags: mysql

It is a table for storage log / activity:

`log [id, date, time]`

I want to retrieve records that have more than X days old by reference to the oldest (the first inserted)

Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM log
WHERE 
(date BETWEEN MIN(date) AND DATE_ADD(MIN(date), INTERVAL X DAY))
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date, Time
```

**UPDATED:**
Although I made the question for a SELECT case, the reality is that I need to delete records (DELETE). Thinking it was the same (I was wrong), the fact is that it can not do a DELETE with a nested SELECT over the same table. (And has a sense).

Seeing that the end was complicated and required more than one sentence, finally I considered separate the code into two queries, first one to get the date for the first inserted element and the second for purge.

```
$sql1 = "SELECT MIN(date) as MinDate FROM `log`";

// Execute the query and gets the result row using whatever database driver[..]
$minDate = $rowQuery["MinDate"]

$sql2 = "DELETE FROM `log` WHERE Date > DATE_ADD('".$minDate."', INTERVAL ".$days." DAY)";
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you aggregate function you should use having and not where

```
SELECT * FROM log
where date in (select date from log 
         having date BETWEEN Min(date) AND DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL X DAY))
GROUP BY date) 
ORDER BY date, time
```

But for select this is better

```
SELECT * FROM `log`
where DateF  BETWEEN (select min(DateF) from `log`) 
            AND DATE_ADD((select min(DateF) from `log`), INTERVAL 2 DAY)
ORDER BY DateF, TimeF
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/85d9f0/4

do the fact that is not possible delete on table with subselect you can use a temporary table 
    create  table temp_log ( dateF datetime(6));

```
insert in temp_log 
select DateF FROM `log`
             where DateF  BETWEEN (select min(DateF) from `log`) 
             AND DATE_ADD((select min(DateF) from `log`)

delete from  `log` as a
inner join temp_log  t on  t.DateF = a.DateF;


drop table temp_log ;
```

Comment: Well if you don't like the subselect could be you can refactoring the query using a join .. but the problem is related to the fact you want select * and this should be in in contrast whit group by date ..anyway ihope my answer is useful

Comment: I really just need the WHERE statement because I'm going to use in a DELETE sentence. I put `SELECT *` as example. It is to purge log records in the table.

Comment: I have update the answer .. hope is what you are looking for .

Comment: if you need filter the result  (for get min(date) ) that mean you need a result this is the subquery (or a join) .. .. but anyway .. i have suggested you a possible solution .. let me know if work or not ..

Comment: I have update the answer avoiding select of id and performing the delete based on date  and adding backtics to the date word

Comment: I have included the query in SQL Fiddle to work better.
Some things that I think are not right and I've changed:

The 'GROUP BY' statement must placed before 'HAVING'. 

The BETWEEN must be added to the minimum value of date (it was not contemplated)

 `SELECT * FROM log
 where DateF in (
  SELECT DateF FROM log
  GROUP BY DateF
  HAVING DateF BETWEEN **Min(DateF)** AND DATE_ADD(Min(DateF), INTERVAL 2 DAY)
 ) 
 ORDER BY DateF, TimeF`

But still, it does not work, you can check it:

[link]http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/85d9f0/2/0/

Comment: Strange.... runs for me: [example in sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/85d9f0/2/0)

Comment: Okay, this last one seems to work. Thanks for you effort, scaisEdge. If you think, we'll leave some time if someone can say something more (maybe more efficent). in the meantime we can clean the answers and comments to the question in order to be more concise and help others.

Comment: I am not able to make it work in the DELETE statement: The MySQL Error  says "you can not specify target table 'log' for update in FROM clause".

In adition now it seems that SQLFiddle not work with the example...

Comment: Could be mysql need an alias for delete on subselected  table .. ia have update the answer .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116720/discussion-between-mikebau-and-scaisedge).

Comment: seeing that in the end the solution could not be done with a sentence I think the simplest is to divide up the problem into two queries. As I updated my original question for explain it.

I don't close the question as answered but scored a reply for your dedication and support. Thank you very much.